# iOS Facebook Access Token To Get User Wall Feed (status)

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, httprequest, feed, facebook-access-token

[DISCLAIMER : None of the access token or ID below here are real]

I've done research for three solid days and no result on how to get user wall feed(post).

I have used

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials
```

and get the access token which is something like this

> access_token=454345994651138|bAMGfuW-ueNXGCahley7ga125HN

and then

```
https://graph.facebook.com/100005939123542/feed?access_token=454345994651138|bAMGfuW-ueNXGCahley7ga125HN
```

It gives me general information such as user's likes, name, id, current city... but **NOT** user's wall posts.

I've learned that there are three types of access token, which is **App Token**, **User Token**, and **Page Token**. In order to get user/feed by using graphAPI, I need to request to get User Token, but there's **NO** information in the lousy Facebook Doc! (Which frustrated me the most!)

In order to generate the user access token, we need to set some permission, generate the access token, and GET the user's wall feed, which is in JSON format.
[image]

**My question is : How do I get the User Access Token in order to get user wall post in iOS Xcode?**

Answer (score 1):

You can get a user access token via facebook's login dialog